# modifying the settings of zbar-sdk ios

Tags: ios, zbar-sdk

I am trying to build an app which scans QR code and barcode of a particular object for which purpose I am using zbar sdk.
I have used an image view and a text view to display the contents of the objects I scanned. I want a beep sound after I scan a particular image and  also I need an option to modify the settings such that if I want I can scan either a bar code or a QR code. I also want to store a history of all the recent images I scanned.

Should I use core data for storing it?
Can I modify settings of zbar sdk?

Comment: Can you please show your code that you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you scan Barcode or QRCode one delegate method will invoked in you main controller, in that method you will get the result text of the Barcode or QRCode, then make your own database and add whatever data you wnat to stored. For this you don't need to touch the Zbar-sdk code. Hope this can be helpful to you.